# solution verification: find center of this group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

we have a group $H$ = $\begin{cases} A= 
\begin{bmatrix}1 & a & b\\ 0 & 1 & c\\0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} : a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$
then find its center $ Z(H)$.
My attempt:      Let $A$ be an arbitrary element in the given group and  $b$ be an element in the center as,
$$ B= \begin{bmatrix}1 & p & q\\ 0 & 1 & r\\0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}, p,q,r \in \mathbb{Q} $$
A little computation gives $$AB= \begin{bmatrix}1 & a+p & b+q+ar \\ 0 & 1 & c+r\\0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $$BA= \begin{bmatrix}1 & a+p & b+q+cp\\ 0 & 1 & c+r\\0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
comparing the two matrices, we get $ ar=cp$, and since a.b.c are arbitrary rational numbers so if $a=c$ then $p=r$ and if $a=2c$ then $p=r/2$ and so on...
   $\implies p=r=0$
hence all matrices of the form $$  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & q\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}, q \in \mathbb{Q} $$ form the required center.
Is the above solution correct? I'm not very sure.  If it is not, please mention exactly what is wrong and why and if it is correct, suggest some alternative solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution is fine. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533096/center-of-heisenberg-group-dummit-and-foote-pg-54-2-2).

Comment: I would simply choose specific values of $a$ and $c$ that ensure $p=r=0$, say $a=0,\ c=1$, then $a=1,\  c=0$.