# Find the center of the group of 3x3 upper triangular matrices with a diagonal of ones

Tags: group-theory

> Let $K$ a field, $G_a$ the additive group of $K$, i.e. $(K,+)$, and $G$ the subgroup of $GL_3(K)$ defined as$$G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b,c\in K\right\}$$
>   Find $Z(G)$.

So let $\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\in Z(G)$. So $$\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&a'&b'\\0&1&c'\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&a'&b'\\0&1&c'\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\iff ac'=a'c.$$

So how can I conclude ?

Comment: See this post :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533096/center-of-heisenberg-group-dummit-and-foote-pg-54-2-2

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled though what's the role of $G_a$ in your question? Probably you have to edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

If your underlying field is finite, say $\mathbb{F}_p= \mathbb{K}$, then you have a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ (and there are only two isomorphism classes of such groups). Then you can see that the matrix 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & c \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
commutes with all the elements and should be lying inside the centre of the group. However a straightforward computation shows that, no other element ( I mean different than the above matrices for $c \in \mathbb{F}_p $) can do that. Hence the centre should be the cyclic group generated by such a matrix in that case. For the infinite case the situation goes as the above and your guessing is correct, the *hints* provided above might help you to sort it out for any field.

You might find this link useful for the finite case (your group is referred as Heisenberg group in there)
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Using different elements of $G$ try to show that $a=c=0$ in your notation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have correctly concluded that $ac' = a'c$, but you are missing quantification: it must hold *for all* $a',c'\in K$. Now, fix some appropriate $a',c'$ to conclude something about $a$ and $c$.