# Showing the Heisenberg group is the central extension of the additive group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, heisenberg-group

Context and some work so far:

I found out about the Heisenberg group on Youtube. I'm a Physics student. I wanted to know more about it, and I realized there was more to learn.

Here is what I found out.

1.) The Heisenberg group is a group of upper triangular matrices of the form:
\begin{pmatrix}
   1 & a & b\\
   0 & 1 & c\\
   0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
I found this out by looking through the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group)

2.) I think I can now construct the corresponding Lie algebra.

Generally,

- A matrix exponential $e^{At} = I + At + \frac{1}{2} A^2t^2+ . . . $
- The derivative  $\frac{d}{dt} e^{At} = $ A  +  A^2 t. . .  = A.e^{At}$

Let

$e^{At} =   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & a(t) & b(t)\\
   0 & 1 & c(t)\\
   0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

then
$\frac{d}{dt} e^{At}|_0= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & a'(0) & b'(0)\\
   0 & 0 & c'(0)\\
   0 & 0 & 0   
   \end{pmatrix}$

with basis:
$ A= \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0   
   \end{pmatrix}$, $B =\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 0   
   \end{pmatrix}$
and
$C =\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0   
   \end{pmatrix}$

Then $[A,B], [A, C]$ and $[B, C]$ can be computed

The central element can then be seen from the commutation relations

Question:

I have read that the Heisenberg group is the central extension of the additive group V. How can one show this?

More context:

I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533096/center-of-heisenberg-group-dummit-and-foote-pg-54-2-2?rq=1) question that tackles the problem without invoking cocycles. It looks at the commutator of two elements of the group and finds the conditions under which the commutator must vanish to find the center of the group. The argument then terminates with the statement that the element that satisfies that argument is isomorphic to the additive group.

More context:
In this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) , under  "On symplectic vector spaces" the abstract group law of the Heisenberg group is given which will be reproduced here : $(v,t).(v',t') = (v+v',t+t', \frac{1}{2} \omega(v,v'))$

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: I just changed the title to "Trying to understand Heisenberg algebra"

Comment: About $\mathbb{C}[t, t^{-1}] \oplus \mathbb{C} K$ the second link has the English translation "Lie algebra of Laurent polynomials plus a one-dimensional space".

Comment: Yeah, I recall reading that. I am still trying to decode that one.

Comment: I want to guess that it is a matrix of a sort over a complex polynomial ring with [t, t^-1] and an extra dimension if this even makes any sense. I am still trying to write a matrix for it.

Comment: I don't know if $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ is just notation for multivariate ring $\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}] = \mathbb{C}[t][t^{-1}]$

Comment: I think 2.7 and 2.8 of this https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0005032.pdf article clarify things a bit

Comment: Yes, $\Bbb C[t,t^{-1}]$ is the ring of Laurent polynomials. I don't understand how $\Bbb C[t,t^{-1}]\oplus\Bbb CK$ is supposed to be the $\cal A$ they described; obviously powers of $t$ commute, unlike the $a_i$s in $\cal A$. I don't understand what you mean by write $\cal A$ as a matrix - how can an algebra be "a matrix"? The link in your last comment mentions a different notion of Heisenberg algebra (which should be obvious, since $\cal A$ is infinite-dimensional).

Comment: Yes, about the matrix part, I mispoke. I have now edited the question.

Comment: one thing I looking at now is trying to understand how the Heisenberg group extends the symplectic group

Comment: According to a reference. http://www.scientificlib.com/en/Mathematics/LX/HeisenbergGroup.html "The Heisenberg group H(V) on (V,ω) (or simply V for brevity) is the set V×R endowed with the group law

$(v,t)\cdot(v',t') =\left (v+v',t+t'+\tfrac{1}{2}\omega(v,v')\right)$ .
The Heisenberg group is a central extension of the additive group V. Thus there is an exact sequence"    Now if I can only decipher the notation.

Comment: I understand the symplectic form part but I don't know what t and t' are and the parenthesis thing altogether.

Comment: Oh, I see what those t's are

Comment: It's not that a Heisenberg group/algebra _extends_ a symplectic group/algebra, but, rather, is _acted_upon_ by a symplectic thingie. From the Stone-vonNeumann theorem, etc.

Comment: Fascinating. Let me just read up on this theorem

Comment: According to Woit 's notes for a fixed scalar, s then center, there is a unique $\rho$. I think this is the statement of the Stone-von Neumann theorem. This is if i read it correctly.

Comment: Something like one to one

Comment: I think the technique to use is "guess and check". Basically conjecture and proof. Can someone tell me if this is true? You guess a representation and check that it meets the rules. You then say conjecture was x, and then the computation is the proof. Is this true? So this would be how one gets the matrix. By guessing!

Answer (score 1):

I've [read](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdditiveGroup.html) that the additive group where the operation is addition.

Let $C(G)$ be the center of the Heisenberg group.

To find the center, $C(G)$ it suffices to find the condition necessary for two heisenberg matrices to form a vanishing Lie bracket.

The below was done in Mathematica not by hand

In practice $\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_1 & b_1\\
             0 & 1 & c_1\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_2 & b_2\\
             0 & 1 & c_2\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$ -  $\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_2 & b_2\\
             0 & 1 & c_2\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_1 & b_1\\
             0 & 1 & c_1\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$ = 0

Hence $\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_1 + a_2 & b_1 + b_2 + a_1 c_2\\
             0 & 1 & c_1 +c_2\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$ - $\begin{pmatrix}
             1 & a_1 + a_2 & b_1 + b_2 + a_2 c_1\\
             0 & 1 & c_1 +c_2\\
             0 & 0 & 1 
             \end{pmatrix}$ = $\begin{pmatrix}
             0 & 0 & - a_2 c_1 + a_1 c_2\\
             0 & 0 & 0\\
             0 & 0 & 0 
             \end{pmatrix}$

So $a_2 c_1 = a_1c_2$  to obtain vanishing commutator

Let center then be matrices of the form
C = $\begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 & b_3\\
         0 & 1 & 0\\
         0 & 0 & 1 
         \end{pmatrix}$

It is easy to check that the commutator with any upper diagonal matrix is vanishing.

So matrices of the form $C$ form the center of the group  $C(G)$

The Heisenberg group is the central extension of the additive group , and the center of the group is C(G)

Let the  quoteient group be $G/C(G)$

According to Wikipedia's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension) on group extensions

$1 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 1$

$C(G)$ of Heisenberg group is the matrices with $(a,b,c)$ as defined above to be $(0,b_3,0)$ as shown by computation.

$C(G)$ is  $N$ the normal subgroup of $G$

so $1 \rightarrow C(G) \rightarrow G \rightarrow R^2 \rightarrow 1$

$ G/C(G)$ ~  $\mathbb{R^2}$

It would seem that it suffices to show this map exists. See page 625 of [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Quantum_Field_Theory_II_Quantum_Electrod/Pk9yyC239scC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22extension%20of%20the%20additive%20group%22&pg=PA625&printsec=frontcover)